# Best practice for Broadcasts, ContentProviders, and ContentRecievers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider, contentobserver, intentservice

Okay so up front I will say that I am new to Android.  I have made a few small projects and played with a  few things and done tons and tons of reading.  So here is the task I am trying to accomplish:

I have a remote service that runs in the foreground of my phone that can send and receive information with other android devices over a wifi network.  APK's on the phone that are built to use this service contain multiple SQLite DB's.  I want these APK's to register there content providers with the service so the service always know where to put data that it recieves (I have accomplished this task).  When data comes in I will identify where it belongs and place it in the right DB (no problem here).  So what would be the best way to notify the correct activity that new data has been received.  Do I register Broadcast Receivers for my service to call?  Will Broadcast Receivers work if the APK has been killed by the OS?  Once the correct activity is loaded would I use a content observer to show the new data?  Why would I use IntentServices?

I'm sorry for so many questions.  Like I said I am learning fast but Android's SKD is massive and there are so many cool things.  I want to make sure I am thinking things through right with best practices and making this very easily maintainable and expandable.  Thanks for any help or advice I can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking what the best way is for a current Activity to know data has changed in the ContentProvider it is reading from, than the answer is a ContentObserver.

Lets say, for examples sake, you have a set of Activities and ContentProviders. Activity A is a list view of items from Content Provider A, and that list view is populated via a CursorAdapter of some kind. Whenever you have a query on a ContentProviders CONTENT_URI, the cursor should automatically monitor the CONTENT_URI for changes via a ContentObserver.

The reason this works is because in the ContentProvider:

1. Your query method calls setNotificationUri on your cursor to the URI that was queried.
2. Whenever a change happens in an insert/update/delete method, you are calling notifyChange on the URI.

If there is additional data that can change in your service that is not tied to a ContentProvider, than you have a few choices on how to pass data. If the Activity is in the same APK as your service, than you could use some sort of static variable, or the application context, or some other custom form of communication. The methods are rather liberal here because you are running in the same VM, so you have a lot of things available to you.

In your situation, it sounds like most activities will be in separate APKs. If that is the case, you will probably want to send out broadcast Intents to let the entire system knwo about the changes. If these changes only matter when an activity is running, you can register a BroadcastReceiver for the life of the Activity that cares about the change. Alternatively, you could put a BroadcastReceiver in the applications manifest, and always receive that change.

That brings us to IntentServices. IntentServices are the "easiest" way to handle long running tasks in Android. All they do, is create a background thread that will handle intents being sent into the service. A common use case is as follows:

1. You receive a broadcast intent that you need to react to (and it will take a while)
2. Send a directed intent (intent with a set component name) to an IntentService with some info from the broadcast intent.
3. IntentService either spawns a new BG thread, or adds the intent to the processing queue on the existing BG thread
4. The onHandleIntent function is called in the IntentService so that you can now process that change using as much processing time as you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I was up to date with the CP's and CO's.  Wasn't sure about the BR's and CI's.  So a broadcast receiver defined in a Manifest file of an APK will allow the APK to receive the broadcast even if its not a running APK (this helps me alot).  Not its just a matter of me figuring out a design to make it all play nice and work how I need it.

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask questions... This kind of design is extremely similar to a major project I am working on.

Comment: Thanks man, that's awesome.  I am trying to design an "in house application".  Right now I'm trying to create a Framework like application I provide a jar interface file for (it handles all IPC to the remote service running).  APK's will use my interface to register their ContentProviders and Message ID's.  I want to make it so when a new message is received on the phone it is added to the correct ContentProvider and the Activity that uses the message type is notified (so I need to make a way to register BroadcastReceivers and dynamically create the broadcasts).  Any advice helps!  Thank you!

Comment: Well, it depends on if the broadcasts are only relevant to the activites while they are open. If so, ContentObservers should be sufficient since your framework is inserting into the CP already. If not, and you need BroadcastReceivers up all the time, put them in your manifest. You can tell the framework to use a unique category that will be added to the change broadcast intent whenever it receives a message.

Comment: Actually, it might just be best to put the URI of the record you inserted right into the Broadcast intent. Probably the simplest and cleanest approach to let your other apps know about the change.

Comment: Just finished implementing the registration of content providers.  They are stored in an array list of an object that holds the uri, authority, apk name, package name, and class name of the activity that registers it.  I think I want to continue ahead using the broadcast receivers.  This will take me a while though as I have never used them and want to create a way to abstractly set them up in the api.  I want dead activities and apk to get them to so...

Comment: So put your BroadcastReceivers in the manifest. Also, you will want to watch for package events in your main class so you can remove any CP's from your "to insert into" list when they get uninstalled.